# How do I make template colors update when I choose them from a list or radio buttons?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I just learning about javascript php html css etc so I'm looking for some guidance on how I'd go about doing the following:

I have a profile creation page which has a form at the top underneath which is a full-sized preview of what the profile looks like. The form is in a full width div above and outside the main content div.

The form allows the user to change the template skin - ie a different stylesheet - by clicking a radio button or using a dropdown list. Preferably as soon as the user changes it would reload the preview (although not the top form if possible)

Also in the form is an upload picture field and a title field (just txt). It would be great it when the user changed these fields it updated the appropriate bits below automatically too. Is there a way to acomplish this without having the user click the submit button and reload the whole page?

Can someone help me get my head round this? Please! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the picture you can use several options out there... Im very familiar with yui uploader this is a good options because the Yui frameworks with any other framework without a problem. But also you can find solve for the same problem, in mootols, jquery and prototype. this is the link http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/ ...

And for change dinamically the css file you can read a little bit here you can find a initial solution http://www.tutorialfeed.org/2009/03/how-to-allow-your-visitors-to-switch.html

Comment: thanks for the link - I'll check them out

Answer (score 0):

you can submit a form via javascript, so you can attach a submitting function to a javascript event, for example:

```
<!-- html -->
<select onChange="javascript:submitMyForm();" />

//js 
function submitMyForm() {
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

if you don't want to reload the whole page you'll have to use an AJAX request. Check a tutorial for this (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
....
```